# Ubuntu 20.04 can't detect my Bluetooth headset microphone

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset

Microphone of my Bluetooth headset (boat rockerz 255) is not detected by Ubuntu 20.04 in the sound settings, there is only one option i.e. Internal microphone.

EDIT - Bluetooth headset is connected and paired and it is detected as a sound device(I can listen songs with it) but microphone of my headset is not detected by ubuntu in the settings.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Is it paired already and not detected as a sound device -or- it isn't detected as a Bluetooth device at all? Are other Bluetooth devices detected and pair correctly? This is pretty much what's missing in your question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I updated the question.